# Using multiple H1 headings through javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

I have created an `<h1>` heading through `createElement("h1")` and given it style. Within my assignment, it is stated that I need to create another `<h1>` heading with the title "Build Your Resume". I have created the code that I thought would work, but nothing is produced from it. I have looked around and see that it is perfectly ok to use multiple `<h1>` headings in HTML. I am not sure what is happening that it is not writing to the web page. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```js
var elemH1 = document.createElement("h1");
elemH1.style.color = "red";
elemH1.style.fontFamily = "tahoma";
elemH1.style.textAlign = "center";
elemH1.innerText = "Kent Butler";
document.body.appendChild(elemH1);

var elemH2 = document.createElement("h2");
elemH2.style.fontFamily = "garamond";
elemH2.style.color = "red";
elemH2.style.fontStyle = "italic";
elemH2.style.textAlign = "center";
elemH2.innerText = "WEB 115.0001";
document.body.appendChild(elemH2);

var title = document.createElement("h1");
title.style.textAlign = "center";
title.innnerText = "Build Your Resume";
document.body.appendChild(title);
```

I am looking for the output to be written and centered. Thank you for any advice/ info.

Comment: Your keyboard stutters: what's `innnerText`? :) Closing as typo.

Comment: uggghhhh... wow. How did I not see that?! freakin typos everytime. Thank you @Amadan

Comment: No worries, happens to everybody. Literally, everybody.

Comment: Try using js linter in order to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 3):

you made a spell error.

title.innnerText = "Build Your Resume"; should be "inner".

Answer (score 0):

You have did spelling mistake :P
title.innnerText = "Build Your Resume";
innerText